# How to set focus to a dynamically generated input field (textbox) in ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I have two textboxes which are dynamically generated, below is the html of the textboxes

[image]

[image: two text boxes]

How do i focus any 1 textbox ?

i tried the below code

```
    $('.answer_1').focus();
```

but that dosent seem to be work, is there any other way where i can set focus to the textbox programmatically?

Comment: are you writing this code in didRender(){}  method??

Comment: no, in a custom method

Comment: you can try to add "$('.answer_1').focus();" this after generating textbox in. and in callback function

Comment: try putting  $('.answer_1').focus(); in didRender().

probably you are calling  $('.answer_1').focus(); even before it is generated and attached to DOM

Comment: @ManojYadav thanks, its working

Comment: Thanks just added it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call $('.answer_1').focus();function after it is being attached to DOM. having said that didRender is a callback method which is called after component is rendered.

```
didRender(){
  $('.answer_1').focus();
}
```